# Refreshing multiple view models from a service class

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

### Context

My project looks like this:

```
+-- screens
|   +-- main_screen.dart
|   +-- details_screen.dart
|   +-- summary_screen.dart
+-- viewmodels
|   +-- main_screen_viewmodel.dart
|   +-- details_screen_viewmodel.dart
|   +-- summary_screen_viewmodel.dart
+-- services
|   +-- caching.dart
|   +-- api.dart
+-- lib.dart
```

Screens use a ViewModel that contains all of the data it requires; any change to the model results in a rebuild of the view:

```dart
// main_screen.dart
class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  final model = MainScreenViewModel();

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<MainScreenViewModel>(
      create: (BuildContext context) => widget.model,
      child: Consumer<MainScreenViewModel>(
        builder: (context, model, child) => Text(model.welcomeMessage)
      )
    );
  }
}
```

This all looks like a fairly standard Provider implementation; time to describe my issue.

### Problem

I have a class called `Caching` that handles the caching of API requests. When a change is made to a resource (e.g. Transactions), I'd like to trigger a refresh of all my viewmodels so the UI displays the updated data.

How can I access the ViewModels from within my Caching class to trigger the update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to handle this using `StreamController`, For example :
Inside my view model i have this portion of code, this line to create listener for the Stream `_basketService.historiesStreamNotifier.listen((value) async {await fetchData();});`

inside the service declare my `StreamController` :

```
StreamController<int> _historiesStreamControllerNotifier =
      StreamController<int>.broadcast();

Stream<int> get historiesStreamNotifier =>
      _historiesStreamControllerNotifier.stream;
```

so whenever i need to refresh my view model from my service i simply call
`_historiesStreamControllerNotifier.sink.add(0);`
This will trigger the callback defined with `.listen(...)`

Comment: You are the most welcome, thanks for correcting my code typo.

Answer (score 0):

On your Services that must update e.g Service A & Service B add this

```
final StreamController<int> _dataStreamController = StreamController<int>.broadcast();
    
Stream<int> get dataStream => _dataStreamController.stream;
```

On your BASE Model, add a listen() method, so its gonna be accessible to all viewmodels

```
  void listen() {
    final aService = locator<ServiceA>();
    final bService = locator<ServiceB>();

    aService.dataStream.listen((_) async {
      notifyListeners();
    });
    bService.dataStream.listen((_) async {
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }
```

On View

```
   BaseView<BViewModel>(
                          onModelReady: (viewModel) {
                          viewModel.listen();
                        },builder: (context, viewModel, child) {
                          return AlignedGridView.count( ...
```

On Services again, once you updated something on service and you want to notify all listening viewmodels on that change

```
... some successful api request ...
      _dataStreamController.sink.add(0);
```